# Rails ActiveRecord: building queries dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to put together a series of classes that can use ActiveRecord to create and execute complex queries dynamically. I feel very comfortable with the whole practice of doing:

```
MyModel.select("id, name, floober").join(:creator).where(:is_active => true)
```

What I'm struggling with is using these things to build up a query w/o being able to determine how many there will be of each possible method (number of joins, number or where clauses, limit, group, etc) ahead of time.  I might have 2 joins, or no joins depending upon where it's called from.

Due to the nature of how I'm getting these things--a list of joins, a list of columns, a list of where clauses, etc--I can blindly chain them together. I have to join the columns together, arrange the joins, chain the where clauses, so I can't loop through the various lists.

I'm trying to avoid writing any raw SQL.

One thing I tried was building up the ruby statement as a string then evaling it at the end, and when I got done I felt dirty like I needed a bath. What I'm looking for is a way to cache the state of my query until all the parts have been accumulated, then execute them.

Have I wandered "off the Rails"?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I was fairly off base on my understanding of the AR query methods. It turns out that ActiveRecord doesn't actually execute the query until you actually try to use the results. As a result it's possible to do things like:

```
model_query = MyModel.select("column12, column32")
model_query = model_query.joins(:user)
model_query = model_query.where(:column12 => true)
```

then after everything is built up you can do

```
model_query.each do |record|
  ...
end
```

The query isn't actually executed until you call each (or whatever method you use that demands the results of the query).

I got this by watching Railscasts [202](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) and [215](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3). I love Ryan Bates.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had been wondering if building a query piecemeal like this would work or if it would result in multiple SQL queries being run.

Comment: I must add that this functionnality works in Rails 2 too ; you can combine named_scope like this, they are chained and executed just on demand.

Comment: This is not working for me..is it available in Rails 3.2.13??

Comment: Anybody interested in this might also be interested in [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope).

Comment: those who say it doesn't work for them...are you attempting to try this in the rails console? In 3.x the rails console often flat out forces interpretation of the AR because it's using some form of I/O evaluation to show you the value on the next line. In 4.2 I think the syntax may have changed slightly. I assure you, though, that this does work--I've been using it since 3.0 and I'm working on both a 4.2 and a 5.0 effort currently.

Comment: 10 years later and Ryan Bates is still a hero for Railscasts

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `send` may be your friend. It's still pretty arbitrary execution of code, but at least you're not using `eval`. It's not entirely clear whether you have these query parts all at once or are building them up over time. If they are present in one http request/response cycle, then iterating through the query parts and doing a `send`, as appropriate would make sense.

OTOH, if you are getting it via Ajax or some other means where the conditions are cumulative, you may have to look at either caching the existing parts or some more exotic solution.